# Problema con URL invocarla con AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

A veces puedo invocarlo así:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Mantenimiento/Encuesta",
        data: { iIdEncuesta: iIdEncuesta },
        success: function (oDatos) {
            $("#divEncuesta").html(oDatos);
        }
    });
```

y otras de esta forma:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Encuesta",
        data: { iIdEncuesta: iIdEncuesta },
        success: function (oDatos) {
            $("#divEncuesta").html(oDatos);
        }
    });
```

No se a ciencia cierta cual puede ser el problema y como debo proceder al respecto.

Comment: ¿Puedes especificar cuál es exactamente tu problema?

Comment: lo más seguro es que tu URL sea relativa, coloca la url completa y listo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema seguramente se debe a la `URL` desde donde ejecutas la llamada `ajax`. En ambos casos usas [`path relativos`](http://librosweb.es/libro/xhtml/capitulo_4/enlaces_relativos_y_absolutos.html) y es precisamente por esto que algunas veces funciona con una ruta y otras veces con la otra.

### Solución:

Realiza siempre las llamadas `ajax` indicando el `path absoluto` al `endpoint`.

Suponiendo que el `path absoluto` es `/api/Mantenimiento/Encuesta`, entonces la llamada `ajax` deberías hacerla así:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/Mantenimiento/Encuesta",
    data: { iIdEncuesta: iIdEncuesta },
    success: function (oDatos) {
        $("#divEncuesta").html(oDatos);
    }
});
```